# Non planar Petersen Proof using Euler

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

Eulers Identity: n-m+r=2

a)If G is a planar graph which contains no cycles of length less than *g*, then give an improved version of Eulers identity by relating the number of regions to the number of edges.

b)use (a) to show Petersen graph is not planar

I'm thinking i need to relate n with g such that a new euler identity can be written with an inequality instead...not sure how they relate though.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Assume by contradiction it is planar.

Since you know $n,m$ by Euler you get $r$.

**Hint 2** **In the Petersen graph**, If you count the edges by faces, each of the $r$ faces has at least $5$ edges. So your count is at least $5r$.

In this count each edge was counted exactly twice. So your count is exactly $2m$.

This shows 
$$2m \geq 5r$$

See what you get.

Comment: wouldn't that observation give us a new Euler Identity where

3n-m (must be greater than) 6?

with n=10 and m=15 from the petersen graph implying that the petersen is planar?

Comment: @DirkMacdon Yes that is a well known identity in a planar graph.But this doesn't imply that the Petersen graph is planar, is just an identity a planar graph must satisfy!

Comment: @DirkMacdon I fixed the proof, in the Petersen graph you have to observe that there are no triangles or quadrilaters as faces. This gives a better inequality.

Comment: but part (a) makes no mention of the Petersen graph, so 2m being greater or equal to 5r isn't a observation i can use to come up with an improved Euler identity?

Comment: @DirkMacdon Part (a) is asking you to solve the problem with $g$ instead of $5$ ;)

Comment: so use 2m (greater than or equal to) gr to create a new Euler, and then plug in our known g, n, and m to show the new identity doesn't hold?

Comment: @DirkMacdon yes